# How to use GitHub Pages with Sveltekit?

Tags: github, github-pages, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I've been trying to deploy a website on the free hosting platform provided by github, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it configured with svelte/sveltekit. I usually use Svelte + Vite to deploy my web pages locally but I would like to be able to share them publicly.

I have tried making a repo called `[username].github.io` and then putting my webpage in a folder within that repo, but it ends up just displaying the README and when I try to route to the folder, it gives me a 404.
I've also looked at a lot of the tutorials that show how to do it, but I think they are most, if not all outdated now.

If anyone has any tips they've managed to do it recently, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Have you looked at the [SvelteKit docs for deploying to GitHub pages](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#github-pages)?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. And I looked at the official docs, no luck though...

Comment: @GeoffRich Wow I can't believe I didn't find this, thanks!

Comment: @GeoffRich I tried their solution and it also didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

I also followed the [SvelteKit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#github-pages) as suggested by [Geoff Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75796127/how-to-use-github-pages-with-sveltekit#comment133735229_75796127), but had the same issue as you: It deployed the `README.md` from the root of my repo instead of the pages built with SvelteKit.

What fixed it for me was to [disable the Jekyll build process](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#static-site-generators) by creating an empty file named `.nojekyll` at the root of my repo.

Answer (score 2):

I went into the same problem. I used description in the [Docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static) and had to create the `.nojekyll` in the static folder. **Make sure**, that you use the `Git Workflow` described in the documention, otherwise you will stay with the `README.md`.

You should also consider to adjust your pathing for `href` etc. like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { base } from '$app/paths';
</script>

<a href="{base}/">Home</a>
```

Otherwise your routing won't work properly (at least this was the case for me).